# Wpf Form Alignment & Resize

Tags: wpf, resize, alignment

I'm trying to make a form in wpf but i have some alignment issues.

This form is special since is made of a set of rows with diferent number of colums.

Here is what I got so far:
[image]

I have 2 problems.

1) **Alignment**

How do I align a textbox from one row with the textbox from the rowe underneath if both rows have diferent number of columns.

I would like to align it like this:
[image]

The left side of T1 to the left side of T3 and the right side of T2 to the right side of T3.
In resize T3 should stretch and T1 and T2 get closer to eachother.

2) **Resize**

Each column height is a percentage of the parent grid height `<RowDefinition Height="62*"/>` and the TextBoxes and Labes are floating with `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`, I thought if i would do it that way when I reduce the height of the form TextBoxes would get closer to eachother but they don't and some TextBoxes are cutted out of the screen.

Here is the XAML Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="my.Controles.Clientes.ControlVerClientes"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="1900" Loaded="ControlVerClientes_Load">
    <Grid Background="Gold" >
        <Grid Name="SubInterfazAdministrarClientes">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="55*"    />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"    />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"    />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column ="0">
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxBuscarCliente" Grid.Row="0" TextChanged="TextBoxBuscarCliente_Change"/>
                    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxBuscarClientes" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,0" SelectionChanged="ListBoxBuscarClientes_SelectionChanged"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column ="1">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="680" Margin="10,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="65*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <Label Content="Nombre" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Width="76" />
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Nombre}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="220" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Content="Apellido" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Apellido}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="220"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid  Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <Label Content="Documento" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="22" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Documento}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="220"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Label Content="Descuento Fijo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="124"/>
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="150" PreviewTextInput="TextboxValidacionNumerica"/>
                                <Label Content="%" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="130,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" Width="19" RenderTransformOrigin="0.395,0.294" Background="Transparent"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label Content="Estado" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="124"/>
                                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" Width="150" Text="{Binding Estado}" DisplayMemberPath="Estado" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>


                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <Label Content="Telefono 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Telefono1}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="220"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Content="Telefono 2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="23"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Telefono2}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="220"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                        <Label Content="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="23"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Email}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="578"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                        <Label Content="Direccion" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="22" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Direccion}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="578"/>
                    </Grid>


                    <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                        <Label Content="Hotel/Habitacion" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="22" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Hotel_Habitacion}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="578"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="6">
                        <Label Content="Contacto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="138"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="96" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Contacto}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="578"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                        <Label Content="{Binding ClienteActual.InfoCreacion}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="578"/>
                    </Grid>


                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Also if you know a better way to do this I would love to hear it.
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Alignment**

For this , you need to remove `Width`, set `HorizontalAlignment = Strecth`, and match right margins of T2 and T3.

**2. Recommended Layout**

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid Background="Gold" >
        <Grid Name="SubInterfazAdministrarClientes">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="34*"    />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="102*"    />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37*"    />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column ="0">
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxBuscarCliente" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxBuscarClientes" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column ="1">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="680" Margin="10,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="120*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="65*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <Label Content="Nombre"/>
                                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Nombre}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <Label Content="Apellido"  />
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Apellido}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid  Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                                <Label Content="Documento" />
                                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Documento}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="108*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="91*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                                    <Label Content="Descuento Fijo"/>
                                    <TextBox  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" />
                                    <Label Content="%"  Background="Transparent" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                    <Label Content="Estado" />
                                    <ComboBox Text="{Binding Estado}" DisplayMemberPath="Estado" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="135*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                                <Label Content="Telefono 1" />
                                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Telefono1}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <Label Content="Telefono 2"/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Telefono2}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                            <Label Content="Email" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Email}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                            <Label Content="Direccion" />
                            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Direccion}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                            <Label Content="Hotel/Habitacion"/>
                            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Hotel_Habitacion}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="6">
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                            <Label Content="Contacto"/>
                            <TextBox Height="96" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClienteActual.Contacto}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                        <Label Content="{Binding ClienteActual.InfoCreacion}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="578"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you want row height to collapse when you resize Window, that may not be the best thing to do, because there must be some meaningful height below which form will become useless. You can experiment with `MinHeight` values.